# selecting element in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to log onto a webpage with python selenium.  I've found an element and it is enabled, but when I try to send_keys() to it I get an error.  The main thing (I think) in the error output is

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
```

My code is

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import contextlib

with contextlib.closing(webdriver.Firefox()) as driver:
    driver.get('http://www.etoro.com/au')
    elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name('inputUsername')
    print 'enabled:', elem.is_enabled()
    print 'selected:', elem.is_selected()
    elem.send_keys('myusername')
```

And the output is

```
enabled: True
selected: False
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "3_trying_again.py", line 10, in <module>
elem.send_keys('ianafterglow')
  File "/Users/ian/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 303, in send_keys
self._execute(Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ELEMENT, {'value': typing})
  File "/Users/ian/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 385, in _execute
return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/Users/ian/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 173, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Users/ian/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 166, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Stacktrace:
at fxdriver.preconditions.visible (file:///var/folders/5b/ym07nh6d74gcn_773ynwqkth0000gn/T/tmpN1MV8l/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:8959:12)
at DelayedCommand.prototype.checkPreconditions_ (file:///var/folders/5b/ym07nh6d74gcn_773ynwqkth0000gn/T/tmpN1MV8l/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:11618:15)
at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///var/folders/5b/ym07nh6d74gcn_773ynwqkth0000gn/T/tmpN1MV8l/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:11635:11)
at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (file:///var/folders/5b/ym07nh6d74gcn_773ynwqkth0000gn/T/tmpN1MV8l/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:11640:7)
at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///var/folders/5b/ym07nh6d74gcn_773ynwqkth0000gn/T/tmpN1MV8l/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:11582:5)
```

So, what do I need to do?

Comment: Try this elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name('inputUsername')
   
 action = webdriver.ActionChains(driver)
    
 action.click(elm).perform();

Comment: fails on the action.click(elem).perform() line with error selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the username field to be visible, you need to move cursor to the login link:

```
....

driver.get('http://www.etoro.com/au')
action = webdriver.ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element(driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    './/a[@class="top-link"]/span[text()="Login"]'
))
action.perform()
# TODO Need to wait until the `inputUsername` field is visible
elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name('inputUsername')
...
```

Comment: fails on the line './/a[@class="top_link"]/span[text()="Login"]' with error selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//a[@class=\"top_link\"]/span[text()=\"Login\"]"}

Comment: @user2472657, I cannot reproduce your problem. The code works without the error. FYI, here's the exact code I ran: http://codepad.org/DfdPxwNG

Comment: issue was underscore versus hyphen in top-link.  How embarrassing!  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use explicit waits:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASSNAME, "inputUsername"))
)

...
```

Comment: the suggested fix code runs successfully, but the program fails in the same way as originally at the elem.send_keys('myusername') line with selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with

Answer (score 0):

I know that this problem is solved , 
I got stuck in similar problem and same error
I have fixed it by just make my script sleep for 2 seconds then resume it was just Connection speed problem

```
...
time.sleep(2)
...
```

don't forget to import time module

```
import time
```

wish that help anyone in future :D

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, selenium was not able to focus and open the login modal. Instead it was focusing on the next element. This was the locator I was using:

```
elem = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//nav[2]/ul/li[3]/a").click()
```

I just changed [3] with [2] and it was able to locate the element and open the modal:

```
elem = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//nav[2]/ul/li[2]/a").click()
```